# Why am I not seeing any marker clusters in my custom Google map?

Tags: google-maps

I really hope you can help because I have been pulling my hair out on this one all day!
We are in the process of developing an estate agency website and as part of this I am looking to develop a cluster map for the homepage which will have links to all of the properties.

I have got the map geocoding a couple of dummy locations from the addresses that I added but when I have added the code to create a cluster it does not appear to be working.
I am starting to think I have not added enough locations for this to click in but the demo's I have seen around have as little as 2 markers.

Below is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/data.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {

        var myOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(54, -2), zoom: 2, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var addressArray = new Array("3 Ard Na Cluana, Warrenpoint, BT34 3GY","19 Great Georges Street, Warrenpoint","Warrenpoint","BT34 3FS","15 Ard Na Cluana, Warrenpoint, BT34 3GY","10 Carrowmenagh Lane, Maghera","Belfast","49.286955, -123.118479");
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var markers = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            geocoder.geocode( { "address": addressArray[i]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: results[0].geometry.location});
                markers.push(marker);
                markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
            }
});
}

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
        }

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px; height: 400px;">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
initialize();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate if you could test and any help or suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`geocode()` is asynchronous method and needs some time to finish. `markerCluster` is created before `markers` is populated. One option is to create `markerCluster` before `for` loop and use

```
markerCluster.addMarker(marker, true);
```

in `geocode()` method. For example:

```
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            geocoder.geocode( { "address": addressArray[i]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: results[0].geometry.location});
                markers.push(marker);
                markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
map.fitBounds(markerBounds);

                markerCluster.addMarker(marker, true);
            }
});
}

        //var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
        }
```