# Set Marker Clusterer async after Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Maps v3 on my webpage which will be set with a lot of markers (3000 - 5000).

This is my shortened code for this now:

```
function initialize(){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: Routing.generate('turn_getajaxfirstpoiofallturns'),
        async: false
    })
    .done(function(response){
        firstPoiOfAllTurns = response;
        for (var i = 0; i < firstPoiOfAllTurns.length; ++i) {
            markers.push(addMarker(map, firstPoiOfAllTurns[i].pois[0], firstPoiOfAllTurns[i].id, '' ,infowindow));
         }
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
    });

    var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15};
    var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I want to get rid of the `async: false` part of this code, so that the site will work even if the markers are not set yet. This works so far, but the MarkerClusterer won't be set if i take the `async: false` away. So the Markers will be shown, but the map is really slow without the Cluster.

I then tried to take the 2 lines of code also in the `.done` function, but it didn't worked either.

How can i set the markerclusterer async to the Map so that the Markers will be shown clustered after the ajax function finished?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I not seeing any marker clusters in my custom Google map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550132/why-am-i-not-seeing-any-marker-clusters-in-my-custom-google-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create marker clusterer before ajax call and add each created marker to marker clusterer in for loop:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < firstPoiOfAllTurns.length; ++i) {
        // markers.push(addMarker(map, firstPoiOfAllTurns[i].pois[0], firstPoiOfAllTurns[i].id, '' ,infowindow));

        mc.addMarker(addMarker(map, firstPoiOfAllTurns[i].pois[0], firstPoiOfAllTurns[i].id, '' ,infowindow), true);
     }
```

I assume that `addMarker()` create a new marker.

Comment: Tried it out again today, i could solve it with `mc.addMarker(addMarker(map, firstPoiOfAllTurns[i].pois[0], firstPoiOfAllTurns[i].id, '' ,infowindow)); mc.draw();` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to move the creation and initialization of the clusterer inside the call back function that creates the markers:

```
.done(function(response){
    firstPoiOfAllTurns = response;
    for (var i = 0; i < firstPoiOfAllTurns.length; ++i) {
        markers.push(addMarker(map, firstPoiOfAllTurns[i].pois[0], firstPoiOfAllTurns[i].id, '' ,infowindow));
     }
     var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15};
     var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
})
```

Comment: That was the first thing that came into my mind, but it won't change a thing :/ But there's no error, i can't tell why it's not working sadly